# How to test command line arguments processing

Tags: unit-testing, testing, command-line-arguments

I have a program that receives command line arguments (in my case, it's a Scala program that uses [Argot](https://github.com/bmc/argot)). A simplified use case would be something like:

`sbt "run -n 300 -n 50"`

And imagine that the app should only accept (and print) numbers between `0` and `100`, meaning it should discard `300` and print only `50`.

What's the best approach to test it? Is unit testing appropriated? Instead of processing the arguments in the `main` maybe I should refactor a function and test the function?

Comment: Factor it out and unit test the individual components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test the very act of passing arguments to your program then you'll be required to perform a blackbox integration/system test (not an unit test):

> Black-box testing is a method of software testing that examines the functionality of an application without peering into its internal structures or workings. See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).

Otherwise, do as Chris said and factor out the code to test the underlying logic without testing the act of receiving an argument.